# Filepond with ASP .NET: "load" function in "server" declaration never fires

Tags: asp.net, server, load, filepond

I am using the integration version of Filepond with Pintura.

When I load files, the 'process' function inside the 'server' declaration works fine, but when I need to display the uploaded files in an array and use the 'addFiles' function, the 'load' function inside the 'server' declaration never works. it shoots up

If I have the files in the 'files' property, I also see that the 'load' function is not used but also 'process' is used.

Could someone please explain to me how these functions work? I have read the Filepond documentation, but there is nothing specific on this topic.

My code:

```
        var lfiles = [
            {
                source: "https://localhost:44308/Samples/Filepond/Uploads/CPT001.png",
                option: {
                    type: "local",
                },
            },
            {
                source: "https://localhost:44308/Samples/Filepond/Uploads/CPT009.png",
                option: {
                    type: "local",
                },
            },
            {
                source: "https://localhost:44308/Samples/Filepond/Uploads/CPT010.png",
                option: {
                    type: "local",
                },
            },
        ];

        // Default FilePond field
        const pondDefault = FilePond.create(document.querySelector('.default'), {
            /* FilePond properties */
            acceptedFileTypes: ['image/png', 'image/jpeg'], // FilePondPluginFileValidateType Plugin
            allowBrowse: true, // FilePond Propertie
            allowDrop: true, // FilePond Propertie
            allowFilePoster: true, // FilePondPluginFilePoster Plugin
            allowFileSizeValidation: true, // FilePondPluginFileValidateSize Plugin
            allowFileTypeValidation: true, // FilePondPluginFileValidateType Plugin
            allowMultiple: true, // FilePond Propertie
            allowPaste: true, // FilePond Propertie
            allowProcess: true, // Don't show in FilePond or ImageFilePoster Object ***
            allowRemove: true, // FilePond Propertie
            allowReorder: true, // FilePond Propertie
            allowRevert: true, // Don't show in FilePond or ImageFilePoster Object ***
            credits: true, // Don't show in FilePond or ImageFilePoster Object ***
            filePosterItemOverlayShadowColor: [116, 120, 217],
            filePosterItemOverlaySuccessColor: [23, 70, 149], // [85, 10, 189],
            filePosterMaxHeight: 512, // FilePondPluginFilePoster Plugin
            itemInsertLocation: 'after', // FilePond Propertie
            instantUpload: true,
            labelFileProcessing: 'Downloading',
            labelFileProcessingComplete: 'Download complete',
            labelTapToCancel: 'tap to cancel',
            labelTapToUndo: 'tap to undo',
            maxFiles: 20, // FilePond Propertie
            maxFileSize: '4MB', // FilePondPluginFileValidateSize Plugin
            maxTotalFileSize: '80MB', // FilePondPluginFileValidateSize Plugin
            maxParallelUploads: 2, // FilePond Propertie
            server: {

                load: (source, load, error, progress, abort, headers) => {
                    console.log("load");

                    var myRequest = new Request(source);
                    fetch(myRequest).then(function (response) {
                        response.blob().then(function (myBlob) {
                            load(myBlob)
                        });
                    });
                },

                process: (fieldName, file, metadata, load, error, progress, abort, transfer, options) => {
                    console.log("Process");

                    // fieldName is the name of the input field
                    // file is the actual file object to send
                    const formData = new FormData();
                    // formData.append(fieldName, file, file.name);

                    //console.log(fieldName);
                    //console.log(file);
                    //console.log(metadata);
                    // return;

                    formData.append("IdAviso", '0000000001');
                    formData.append("FileName", file.name);
                    formData.append("ImageData", file);
                    formData.append("ImageHeight", '700');
                    formData.append("ImageWidth", '1440');
                    formData.append("ImageType", file.type);
                    formData.append("FileIndex", metadata.fileindex); // e.detail.file.getMetadata("index")
                    formData.append("FileSize", file.size);

                    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    request.open('POST', 'FilepondReceiver.aspx');

                    // Should call the progress method to update the progress to 100% before calling load
                    // Setting computable to false switches the loading indicator to infinite mode
                    request.upload.onprogress = (e) => {
                        console.log("Process --> Progress");
                        progress(e.lengthComputable, e.loaded, e.total);
                    };

                    // Should call the load method when done and pass the returned server file id
                    // this server file id is then used later on when reverting or restoring a file
                    // so your server knows which file to return without exposing that info to the client
                    request.onload = function () {
                        if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 300) {
                            // the load method accepts either a string (id) or an object
                            console.log("Process --> Load");
                            load(request.responseText);
                        } else {
                            // Can call the error method if something is wrong, should exit after
                            error('oh no');
                        }
                    };

                    request.send(formData);

                    // Should expose an abort method so the request can be cancelled
                    return {
                        abort: () => {
                            // This function is entered if the user has tapped the cancel button
                            request.abort();

                            // Let FilePond know the request has been cancelled
                            abort();
                        },
                    };
                },

                revert: null,

                remove: null,
            },
            styleButtonRemoveItemPosition: 'right',
            styleProgressIndicatorPosition: 'right',
            files: lfiles,

            /* Image Editor plugin properties */
            imageEditor: {
                // used to create the editor, receives editor configuration, should return an editor instance
                createEditor: openEditor,

                // Required, used for reading the image data
                imageReader: [createDefaultImageReader],

                // optionally. can leave out when not generating a preview thumbnail and/or output image
                imageWriter: [
                    createDefaultImageWriter,
                    // optional image writer instructions, this instructs
                    // the image writer to resize the image to match a width of 384 pixels
                    {
                        //store: (state, options, onprogress) =>
                        //    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        //        const { dest, imageState } = state;

                        //        // create a formdata object to send to the server
                        //        const formData = new FormData();

                        //        formData.append("IdAviso", '0000000001');
                        //        formData.append("FileName", dest.name);
                        //        formData.append("ImageData", dest);
                        //        formData.append("ImageHeight", '700');
                        //        formData.append("ImageWidth", '1440');
                        //        formData.append("ImageType", dest.type);
                        //        formData.append("FileSize", dest.size);

                        //        //console.log('name: ' + dest.name + ', ' + 'size: ' + dest.size + ', ' + 'type: ' + dest.type + '\n\n');
                        //        //return;

                        //        // create a request object
                        //        const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        //        request.open('POST', 'FilepondReceiver.aspx');

                        //        // show progress in interface
                        //        request.upload.onprogress = onprogress;

                        //        // catch errors
                        //        request.onerror = () =>
                        //            reject('oh no something went wrong!');
                        //        request.ontimeout = () =>
                        //            reject('oh no request timed out!');

                        //        // handle success state
                        //        request.onload = () => {
                        //            if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 300) {
                        //                // store request in state so it can be accessed by other processes
                        //                state.store = request;
                        //                resolve(state);
                        //            } else {
                        //                reject('oh no something went wrong!');
                        //            }
                        //        };

                        //        // start uploading the image
                        //        request.send(formData);
                        //    }),

                        targetSize: {
                            width: 1440,
                            height: 700,
                            upscale: true,
                        },
                    },
                ],

                // used to generate poster images, runs an editor in the background
                imageProcessor: processImage,

                // Pintura Image Editor properties
                editorOptions: {
                    // pass the editor default configuration options
                    ...getEditorDefaults(),

                    // we want a custom crop
                    imageCropAspectRatio: 16 / 7.78,
                    imageCropMaxSize: { width: 8192, height: 8192 },
                },

                // map legacy data objects to new imageState objects, uncomment if you've used FilePond with version 6 of Pintura and are loading old file metadata
                // legacyDataToImageState: legacyDataToImageState,
            },
        });
```